# Is there a way to find out if a JS function return JSX or not?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a dynamic list. Developers can either provide a URL or a component for that list. Both of them are basically functions:

```
<List
    {...otherProps}
    create={params => `create_a_dynamic_url`}
/>

<List
   {...otherProps}
   create={Form}
/>
```

and in my `List.jsx` I have a `create` prop that is a function.

I should either directly render it using `{create}` or call it first and then navigate the user to that URL.

For both of them, the `typeof` operator returns `function`. Is there a way to find out if their return value is JSX or not?

Comment: ...why do you need to check that? You basically never call React components as a function...

Comment: JSX is just syntactic anyway - the second function returns an _element_. It would be helpful to provide some context; right now this is likely an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @JaredSmith, for dynamic systems, the power of reflection is something is almost any programming language has. Sometimes we don't have another choice.

Comment: You won't be able to distinguish them. Would recommend using different props for the two use cases.

Comment: Or change the function API, so the function returns either a URL or a component, then you can check the type of the return value rather than treating it completely differently.

Answer (score -1):

It is not reliably possible to check if the function is a React *component*,
but it might help you to check for the React *element* (which is easy).

#### Check the React element

You can call the function yourself, assign the return value to a variable, and check if that is a React *element*.

```
function App(){
    return <>
        <List id={'A'} create={ props => <>(My React component)</> } />
        <List id={'B'} create={ params => `create_a_dynamic_url` } />
    </>;
}
```

```
export const List = props => {
    const { create, id } = props;

    // -- Check for the React components `.name`:
    console.log('(List.js) create.name:', id, create?.name);

    // --
    // Create either a ReactElement from the ReactComponent,
    // or the string from the string constructor function:
    // --
    const myElementOrString = create();

    // -- Check for string or ReactElement:
    const isString = typeof myElementOrString === 'string';
    const isReactElement = !isString;

    // --
    return <>
        <p>{ id }</p>
        <div>
            <b>The React element is:</b>
            { isReactElement ? myElementOrString : '(none)' }
        </div>
        <p>
            <b>The string is:</b>
            { isString ? '"' + myElementOrString + '"': '(none)' }
        </p>
    </>;
};
```

Alternatively you could also check for `myElementOrString.hasOwnProperty('$$typeof')` or other React specific properties,
but I would be careful with that, because these (or some of them) are "implementation details" you should not rely on.

#### The `.name` property

Also note that the function received by your `List` component via the `create` property
will have a `.name` property, which will be different depending on some circumstances, e.g.:

- an anonymous function will have the name "create" (the property name)
- a named component will have the name of the component
- a named function will have the name of the function
- ... ?

You might be able to check the `.name` property, but I think that approach would not
be reliable (e.g. this depends on that the developer knows about this, e.g. has to name the function in a specific way.)